# Null pointer exception in kernel while doing write operation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am a windows driver programmer, who is also a complete beginner in linux kernel development. im trying out simple linux kernel modules.

I have written a parallel port driver as in the following code and could successfully load this driver.

I have created a char device node using command mknod with same major and minor numbers as in the code. I have tried reading from the file using cat command and i found it was working fine. While i tried writing the same device using command cat in.txt>/dev/parallel_dev the prompt shows a message "killed" and in dmesg, it has shown unable to handle kernel NULL pointer exception.

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>    
#include<linux/kernel.h>    //kprintf
#include<linux/module.h>    //kmalloc
#include<linux/types.h>
#include<linux/fs.h>        //fileoperations,register_chrdev
#include<linux/slab.h>      
#include<linux/uaccess.h>   //copy from/to user 
#include<linux/ioport.h>    //check_region
#include<linux/interrupt.h>
#include<linux/delay.h>

static int parallel_open(struct inode* p_node, struct file* p_file);
static int parallel_release(struct inode* p_node, struct file* p_file);
static ssize_t parallel_read(struct file* p_file, char* buf, size_t count, loff_t* f_pos);
static ssize_t parallel_write(struct file* p_file, const char* buf, size_t count, loff_t* f_pos);
static irqreturn_t parallel_interrupt(int irq,void* dev);

static const int   major_no = 709;
static const char* dev_name = "parallel_tryout";
#define par_base 0x378
int port;
int* parallel_buffer;

struct file_operations fops = {
    .read = parallel_read,
    .write = parallel_write,
    .open = parallel_open,
    .release = parallel_release,
};

static int parallel_init(void)
{
    int reg_result; 

    int irq_req_result;
    unsigned int irq_num = 7;


    printk("Entered init");
    printk("Initializing parallelport dev with major %d",major_no);
    reg_result = register_chrdev(major_no, dev_name, 0);
    if(reg_result < 0 )
    {
        printk("Error registering char dev: %s",dev_name);
    }
    parallel_buffer = kmalloc(16,GFP_KERNEL);
    if(parallel_buffer==NULL)
    {
        printk("Error allocating memory for: %s",dev_name);
    }
    printk("Port registration");
    request_region(0x378,1,"parallelport");
    if(port)
    {
        printk("Error allocating port");
    }
    parallel_buffer = inb(par_base);
    if(parallel_buffer != NULL)
    {
        printk("Allocated buffer");
    }
    irq_req_result = request_irq(irq_num,parallel_interrupt,IRQF_SHARED,dev_name,parallel_buffer);
    return 0;
}
static void parallel_exit(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev(major_no, dev_name);  
    release_region(0x378,1);                
}
static int parallel_open(struct inode* p_node, struct file* p_file)
{
    printk("parallel driver opened from device: %s",dev_name);
    return 0;
}
static int parallel_release(struct inode* p_node, struct file* p_file)
{
    printk("Memory driver closed from device: %s",dev_name);
    return 0;
}
static ssize_t parallel_read(struct file* p_file, char* buf, size_t count, loff_t* f_pos)
{
    copy_to_user(buf,parallel_buffer,1);
    printk("Copied data:%s ",buf);
    printk("Memory driver read from device: %s",dev_name);
    return 0;
}
static ssize_t parallel_write(struct file* p_file, const char* buf, size_t count, loff_t* f_pos)
{

    copy_from_user(parallel_buffer,buf,1);
    printk("Copied data:%s ",parallel_buffer);
    printk("Memory driver written from device: %s",dev_name);

    return 0;
}

static irqreturn_t parallel_interrupt(int irq,void* dev)
{
    irqreturn_t return_value;
    printk("parallel interrupt detected!!!!");
    return return_value;
}
module_init(parallel_init);
module_exit(parallel_exit);
```

what could be the possible reason for this, and thanks in advance.

Comment: I have to ask this, but does `ls /dev/parallel_dev` display the dev? Right?

Comment: yes, it shows  in /dev/parallel_dev and i have changed its permission to 666

Comment: `static const char* dev_name = "parallel_tryout";` Why?

Comment: register_chrdev() requires dev_name right?

Comment: yes and is that name "parallel_tryout" ?

Comment: `printk`'s `%s` format specifier expects a null-terminated string.